# Turning off DHCP on Rails webserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, puma, webrick, dhcp

I'm running Puma webserver for Rails on `localhost:3000`. I'm at my office connected to the network.

Our systems admin has asked me if I'm running some kind of server and that its handing out DHCP addresses to everybody and slowing down everything.

How do I turn off DHCP for Puma, or Webrick, or is there a better solution to my problem?

Basically how to I use Rails server but stop myself from messing with my office's network, while still being connected to the network?

Comment: That's not how it works. A rails server doesn't just start to hand out IP addresses to other hosts on the same subnet. I'd say your IT guy is playing you for a fool, or is just confused in general.

Comment: It's possible your machine is running a dhcp server, but that will be unrelated to rails

Comment: @jforberg Hah im dumb. I think I figured it out. It wasn't the rails server. It was that I left internet sharing option enabled on my mac... i think.